# User Relationship

Tags: meta-query, user-meta, wp-user-query

I have created a custom registration page, whereby a person will receive a code from another user and type in a code upon registering. If the code matches, i need the user who has just registered to become related to the user who they received the code from. Note i am saving these codes in a custom plugin table.

So you will have a one to many relationship, where a user can have many sub users. If possible i need to be able to extend that further so that a sub user could also have many sub users. So the first relationship and my priority right now would be:

```
USER
 |
SUB-USER
```

I would then like to be able to do this:

```
USER - A
 |
SUB-USER B  -------
    |             |
 SUB-USER C    SUB-USER D
```

User B is related to User A. User C and D are related to B.

I know we can make use of the  and [Update User Meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) and query these relationships with the following query, i would just like some advice about creating this sort of relationship going forward.

```
$users_sub_users = new WP_User_Query( array(
   'meta_key' => 'user',
   'meta_value' => $user_id
) );
```

Comment: I wonder why, going in, you want to establish or imply a hierarchy. Seems to me that each user would get a user_meta array whose elements would probably just be other user_id's. Advising you any further would require knowing a little to a lot more about what uses you anticipate making of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I were you, I would use the wp_usermeta table. it is possible to add information to this table easily:

```
add_user_meta(NEW_USER_ID, "PARENT_USER_ID",USER_ID,true);
```

USER_ID: the Id of top level user, (In your case id of user A)
"PARENT_USER_ID": some key that you could search and find result based on
NEW_USER_ID: The Id of sub_user 
true: To let many user be sub user of the same user

for instance if USER A id is 41, and the Id of new user (which is B) is 82 your code look like:

```
add_user_meta(82, "PARENT_USER_ID",41,true);
```

then you can search for all users which their PARENT_USER_ID is user_id (in our example 41) and then you will get all sub users for that user.

sample query:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'PARENT_USER_ID', 'meta_value' => '41' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for that ill try this out! To clarify, i am using a plugin to store these codes because there is other information they would like in a separate table/view and there will be other variables that will be displayed here. Would i be able to make use of these update_user_meta functions within the plugin?

Comment: Ok, you can use your preferred plugin, however this is a simple easy way to make relation between your user, you just need to add an action, to add this user_metakey, to one method of plugin which create user.